# Logout based on unauthorized API response

Tags: dart, flutter

I have created Rest API helper like this.

```dart
class Api {
  final String _url = baseUrl + "api/";

  _logout() async {
    // EXIT ALL ONGOING PROCESSES HERE & NAVIGATE TO LOGOUT SCREEN
    await navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Login(),
      ),
    );

    return {'success': false, 'error': 'Authentication failed!'};
  }

  Future get(url) async {
    // Getting token from sharedprefs
    String token = Prefs.prefs.getString("token");

    // Set authorization header
    Map<String, String> headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + token;
    };

    return await http.get(_url + url, headers: headers).then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Valid response
        return convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      } else {
        // 401 Status code
        return _logout();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then in screen/view, I am calling APIs like this.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  Api().get('getdata').then((response) {
      setState(() {
        _data = response;
      })
  });
}
```

#### For Valid/Un-Expired API Token

For successful api response, fetched data will be updated in view using setstate method. It's working perfectly fine.

#### For Invalid/Expired API Token

For invalid token, API will give 401 status code & API helper will navigate to Login screen using _logout() function.

Here, it's not working as expected. Here app pushed to loginscreen, but then it gives me error like this.

> This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.

## My question is,

Is this correct way to do logout based on REST API response?

## Edit:

In simple terms, I want to logout whenever I get unauthorized response in REST API helper.

Also without API helper, writing if-else statement manually for every single place is not feasible.

Comment: the problem is that basically calling apis from within your stateful widgets is incorrect in flutter since your widget can be disposed and then you've lost the response so you have to check whether the widget has been disposed. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html use futurebuilder to automatically logout the user based on api response that is cached instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use scoped_model to manage your app state

check out the package for more info on how this works 
[Link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do same with scoped_model.

Comment: Same problem with state management. Also checked with flutter_block plugin.

Comment: u can wrap it in the root widget and check login state on the build methods

Answer (score 0):

You are on track what you can do is to **navigate** to the **login screen** when the **authentication**  **process fails**

use this to close all previous screen and take the user to login i.
So when the user presses the back button it will close the app instead

```
Navigator.of(context)
        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

And also I think you **API** should **pass** more **info** like a **json** `{status: 'success'}` so you also check the response and the body content to verify the login was successfully

Comment: It's still giving me setState error: "setState() called after dispose()". I think, state management will solve this problem.

Comment: @Hiren you don't have to call set state when navigating away from a particular route

And also if you are using scope model don't call set state instead call the model class dot notifychanges()